# value not print in label Currency conversion

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using Currency conversion.I want to show result on drop down change.Suppose i clicked on india it will chow indian currency on label.

```
protected void DdlFromCurrency_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Result = null;
    string url;

    //Call the web service to get the exchange rate for the two currencies selected by the user 
    url = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=" + DdlFromCurrency.SelectedValue + "&ToCurrency=" + DdlToCurrency.SelectedValue + "";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader Stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    Result = Stream.ReadToEnd();
    doc.LoadXml(Result);
    shw_courenct.Text = DdlFromCurrency.SelectedValue;
}
```

} 
I want to show currency value not the selected item value.

Comment: If you Request this Web Service `http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx` what is the response value it returns...?

Comment: Also You assigned the Drop Down Value to Label `shw_courenct.Text = DdlFromCurrency.SelectedValue;` that's why you got wrong value... You must assign the Response of Web service

Comment: it showing ve dropdown value. how can i use assign value to labal on Response of web service